# Ordinal scale's rangeRoundBands()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building a bar chart that will have a varied number of data points. All the examples I've seen use an ordinal scale for the x axis, then call `rangeRoundBands()` to get the width for the bars.

I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined" when I try to called `.rangeRoundBands()` and as far as I can tell I'm setting the scale up properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/rLzbbec0/1/

```
var globOb = {
bar: {
    height: 390,
    width: 675,
    innerHeight: 300,
    innerWidth: 615,
    margin: {
        bottom: 70,
        left: 40,
        right: 20,
        top: 20
    }
},
barData: [
    { task: "meetingsTask", val: 2.5    },
    { task: "reportsTask", val: 3 },
    { task: "emailsTask", val: 2 },
    { task: "planningTask", val: 1.5 },
    { task: "clientsTask", val: 4 },
    { task: "dataAnalysisTask", val: 3 }
]};

//Set X Scale
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, globOb.bar.innerWidth], .05, .1);

xScale.domain(globOb.barData.map(function(d) {
    return d.task
}));

//Set Y Scale
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(globOb.barData, function(d) {
        return d.val + 1
    })])
    .range([globOb.bar.innerHeight, 0]);


//Grab SVG and set dimensions
var svg = d3.select("#viewport").append("svg")
    .attr("width", globOb.bar.width)
    .attr("height", globOb.bar.height);

//Set the drawing area of the SVG
var inner = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + globOb.bar.margin.left + "," +
        globOb.bar.margin.top + ")")
    .attr("width", globOb.bar.innerWidth)
    .attr("height", globOb.bar.innerHeight);

//Setup Axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .innerTickSize(0)
    .outerTickSize(-globOb.bar.innerHeight)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .innerTickSize(-globOb.bar.innerWidth)
    .outerTickSize(-globOb.bar.innerWidth)
    .orient("left");

//Add X Axis
inner.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (globOb.bar.innerHeight) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

//Add Y axis
inner.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .call(yAxis);


//draw data
inner.selectAll("bar")
    .data(globOb.barData)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
        return d.task.substring(0, d.task.length - 4) + "-bar"
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.task)
    })
    .attr("width", 50) //xScale.rangeRoundBands())
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.val)
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return globOb.bar.innerHeight - yScale(d.val)
    });

console.log(xScale.rangeRoundBands());
```

In the fiddle I have changed the call of `rangeRoundBands()` to a set number to show the chart otherwise draws fine.  At the end I'm using `console.log()` to show the error with `.rangeRoundBands()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ordinal.rangeRoundBands`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal_rangeRoundBands) is a configuration setter, and you cannot call it without arguments, so it generates an error while trying to access the second item `x[1]` (indexed from zero) in the first argument `x`. You can take a look at [the source](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/v3.4.13/src/scale/ordinal.js#L67).

You probably want to use [`ordinal.rangeBand()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal_rangeBand) instead, which:

> Returns the band width. When the scale’s range is configured with rangeBands or rangeRoundBands, the scale returns the lower value for the given input. The upper value can then be computed by offsetting by the band width. If the scale’s range is set using range or rangePoints, the band width is zero.